# How to query the filesystem (NTFS) with SQLite?

Tags: sqlite, filesystems

How can I query the filesystem (NTFS) with SQLite?

Comment: Query it for what? The underlying filesystem?

Comment: Could you describe what you actually want to achieve by this?

Answer (score 4):

Maybe you'll find interesting this article: [Query Anything with SQLite](http://www.ddj.com/database/202802959)

> [...] SQLite has a number of unique
>   features, one of the most interesting
>   of which is virtual tables. With
>   virtual tables, you query not only
>   what is in a database, but what is
>   outside of it as well. **For instance,**
>   **with a little coding, you could use**
>   **SQLite to search through your**
>   **filesystem and issue queries such as**
>   **[...]**

Answer (score 1):

You can't.

WinFS seems to be a solution based on Microsoft SQL Server that runs on top of NTFS. But WinFS is still in development.